# Content type mismatch when consuming java wsdl from .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

There is a wsdl hosted on apache or jboss on a remote server that I am trying to use in my c# project. I have added a service reference in visual studio, which automatically generated an app.config file for me, where the **system.serviceModel** section looks as follows

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ArtesiaWebServicesHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="655360" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://serverpath/ArtesiaWebServices"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ArtesiaWebServicesHttpBinding"
            contract="DAMService.ArtesiaWebServicesInterface" name="ArtesiaWebServicesHttpPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

At runtime, during a method call, I get the following error:

**The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"**; start=""; start-info="text/xml";       boundary="----=_Part_386_1206794365.1374255761229" of the response message **does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)**. If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing messageEncoding property of the binding to "Mtom" instead of "Text"